# Shifting depending on different columns and begining the shift depending on changes in columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, shift

I have a dataframe (here an example)

| Date | UnitId | ServiceDomineId | Interval | ServiceTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 30 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:30 | 20 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 9:00 | 10 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 8:00 | 50 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 9:00 | 10 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 8:30 | 25 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 9:00 | 15 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 9:30 | 30 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:00 | 45 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:30 | 10 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 30 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:30 | 45 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 9:00 | 10 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 8:00 | 30 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 8:30 | 55 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 9:00 | 60 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 8:00 | 35 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 8:30 | 15 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 9:00 | 10 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:00 | 20 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:30 | 35 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 9:00 | 10 |

And I need to have a new column being what happened on the previous Iterval (Note: I actually have the intervals saved as a number, every interval is 1/48 more than the previous one, for example 00:00 is 0, 8:00 would be 16/48, then it is 1/3 or as I have it 0.333333) Also if the previous interval doesn't exist in the Data I have, I would like it to show 0 in that column. Here an example of how it should be.

| Date | UnitId | ServiceDomineId | Interval | ServiceTime | ServiceTimePreviousInterval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 30 | 0 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:30 | 20 | 30 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 9:00 | 10 | 20 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 8:00 | 50 | 0 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 9:00 | 10 | 0 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 8:30 | 25 | 0 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 9:00 | 15 | 25 |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 9:30 | 30 | 15 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:00 | 45 | 0 |
| 01/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:30 | 10 | 45 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:00 | 30 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 8:30 | 45 | 30 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 1 | 9:00 | 10 | 45 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 8:00 | 30 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 8:30 | 55 | 30 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 1 | 9:00 | 60 | 55 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 8:00 | 35 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 8:30 | 15 | 35 |
| 02/01/2021 | 1 | 2 | 9:00 | 10 | 15 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:00 | 20 | 0 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 8:30 | 35 | 20 |
| 02/01/2021 | 2 | 2 | 9:00 | 10 | 35 |

I thought about using Pandas function shift, but it whouldn't help when there are missing intervals.
Also thought about using nested for to separate in different dataframes and make the desicion with an if, but it since the complete dataframe is really big, it takes too long.
Do you know how could I do it?

Here an image of the complete dataframe and a comparison of how I see my intervals (float) vs what they are to understand it better.
[image: Here an image of the complete dataframe]

Another logical way I found to do this is

```
df=df.sort_values(['Date','UnitId','ServiceProfileId','Intervals'])
df['ServiceTimePI']=np.zeros(len(df))
df['ServiceTimePI'][0]=0
for i in range(len(df)-1):
  if (df['Date'][i]==df['Date'][i+1]) and (df['UnitId'][i]==df['UnitId'][i+1]) and (df['ServiceProfileId'][i]==df['ServiceProfileId'][i+1]) and (df['Intervals'][i+1]-df['Intervals'][i]<=1/48+0.00000001) and (df['Intervals'][i+1]-df['Intervals'][i]>=1/48-0.00000001):
    df['ServiceTimePI'][i+1]=df['Promedio_ServiceTime'][i]
  else:
    df['ServiceTimePI'][i+1]=0
```

Comment: Why is one of your records showing a service time of 30 and a previous of 30, and another shows a service time of 55 and a previous of 20 when the previous looks to be 30?

Comment: You are absolutely right, it was my mistake, I already corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it orders the dataframe by the columns needed, then creates the new column filled with 0s, since the first value is always going to be 0, then the for just checks if there is a change in the columns and if the interval are half an hour one from the other, if there is no change and the intervals are half an hour from each other, then the value I need is the one from the previous interval, else it is 0.

```py
df=df.sort_values(['Date','UnitId','ServiceProfileId','Intervals'])
df['ServiceTimePI']=np.zeros(len(df))
df['ServiceTimePI'][0]=0
for i in range(len(df)-1):
    if (df['Date'][i]==df['Date'][i+1]) and (df['UnitId'][i]==df['UnitId'][i+1]) and (df['ServiceProfileId'][i]==df['ServiceProfileId'][i+1]) and (df['Intervals'][i+1]-df['Intervals'][i]<=1/48+0.00000001) and (df['Intervals'][i+1]-df['Intervals'][i]>=1/48-0.00000001):
        df['ServiceTimePI'][i+1]=df['Promedio_ServiceTime'][i]
    else:
        df['ServiceTimePI'][i+1]=0
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Can you please supply an explanation of what your code is doing and why it solves the OP's problem?

Comment: First it orders the dataframe by the columns needed, then creates the new column filled with 0s, since the first value is always going to be 0, then the for just checks if there is a change in the columns and if the interval are half an hour one from the other, if there is no change and the intervals are half an hour from each other, then the value I need is the one from the previous interval, else it is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're really checking is if per `UnitId` and `ServiceDomineId` the prior `Interval` is 30 minutes behind.  If so shift that `ServiceTime` down one row within that group, otherwise will with zero.

We can use the `.ne` and `cumsum` to group by consecutive `UnitId` and calculate the timedelta between the prior row and the current row in minutes, and if it equals 30, move the prior `ServiceTime` up one, otherwise fill with zero.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/2021','01/01/2021','01/01/2021','01/01/2021','01/01/2021','01/01/2021','01/01/2021',
  '01/01/2021','01/01/2021','01/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021',
  '02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021','02/01/2021'],
 'UnitId': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
 'ServiceDomineId': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
 'Interval': ['8:00','8:30','9:00','8:00','9:00','8:30','9:00','9:30','8:00','8:30','8:00','8:30','9:00',
  '8:00','8:30','9:00','8:00','8:30','9:00','8:00','8:30','9:00'],
 'ServiceTime': [30,20,10,50,10,25,15,30,45,10,30,45,10,30,55,60,35,15,10,20,35,10]})

df.assign(ServiceTimePreviousInterval = np.where((df.groupby(df['UnitId'].ne(df['UnitId'].shift()).cumsum())
                                                    .apply(lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(x['Interval']) - pd.to_datetime(x['Interval']).shift()).dt.seconds / 60))
                                                    .reset_index()['Interval'] == 30,
                                                  df['ServiceTime'].shift(),
                                                  0
                                                 ))
```

Comment: Yeah, it is by unit and service domine, but also by date and in the actual DataFrame I have a couple more columns, how can I add many columns to your code?

Comment: I also already tried the code as it is, but I'm getting 0s in all rows. Since my intervals are actually not in the datetime format, but as a float, being every half hour 1/48, also tried to change that part to
´´´
.apply(lambda x: (x['Interval'] - x['Interval'].shift())))
                                                    .reset_index()['Interval'] == (1/48),
´´´

Comment: Try providing sample data that is accurate to your actual data

Comment: Ok, I added a little piece of it in the question as an Image.